# Odoo 14.0 moving attachments to filestore fails with PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError

Tags: image, odoo, python-imaging-library, odoo-14

I'm moving attachments from database to filestore to lighten database and it failed with:

```
  File "/home/odoo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/odoo/tools/image.py", line 446, in base64_to_image
    return Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(base64_source)))
  File "/home/odoo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3009, in open
    im = _open_core(fp, filename, prefix, formats)
  File "/home/odoo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2996, in _open_core
    _decompression_bomb_check(im.size)
  File "/home/odoo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2906, in _decompression_bomb_check
    f"Image size ({pixels} pixels) exceeds limit of {2 * MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS} "
PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError: Image size (228554496 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack.
```

Looks like an issue comes from Pillow library [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/tools/image.py#L446). I can update to e.g.`Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 300000000` but wondering how it could affect performance. Anybody has such a issue, how do you dealt with it?

Comment: It shouldn't make an iota of difference to performance, it just allows you to load and process larger images.